# Route print job to a pc instead of a dot matrix printer

Tags: c#, io, legacy

I have a legacy system (black box) that does various calculations and prints to a dot matrix printer.  Instead of printing to a printer, I would like to get rid of the dot matrix printer and connect the legacy system (black box) to another computer and capture the print job, parse the data and store it for later use (store data in use for reporting).

Is this possible?  Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction to accomplish this goal?  The legacy system is currently connected to the following dot matrix printer:
OKI Microline  320 Turbo
http://www.ebay.ca/ctg/OKI-MICROLINE-320-Turbo-Point-Sale-Dot-matrix-Printer-/48464406

Thank you!

Comment: Is the printer connected to the system through the parallel port?

Comment: Yes - printer is connected to legacy system through parallel port

Comment: Take a look at [Printfil](http://www.printfil.com/english.htm).